# FFmpeg UDP audio livestream

Tags: ffmpeg, alsa, udp, audio-streaming

Having trouble getting the following command to stream audio through UDP, is there a parameter missing?

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1 -ar 44100 -f mpegts udp://10.255.255.255:10000?pkt_size=1316
```

The server recognizes it, here is a `tcpdump` on port `10000`:

```
IP 10.255.255.255.54260 > 10.255.255.253.10000: UDP, length 1316
IP 10.255.255.255.54260 > 10.255.255.253.10000: UDP, length 1316
IP 10.255.255.255.54260 > 10.255.255.253.10000: UDP, length 940
IP 10.255.255.255.54260 > 10.255.255.253.10000: UDP, length 1316
IP 10.255.255.255.54260 > 10.255.255.253.10000: UDP, length 1316
```

After looking at the packets in [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org):

```
source         destination    protocol size   description
192 kb/s       44.1 kHz       MPEG-1   1358   Audio Layer 3[Malformed Packet]
10.255.255.255 10.255.255.253 MPEG TS  1358   Source port: 46947  Destination port: distinct
```

I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?213-FFmpeg-with-Wowza-Server-(MPEG-TS)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the command that worked:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:1 -acodec libvo_aacenc -f mpegts udp://10.255.255.255:9999?pkt_size=1316
```